# appending line to a file in a specific location using tcl

Tags: file, insert, append, tcl, line

I am trying to do this:

1. I have a text file which has a line starting with the specific pattern:
   `vvdd vdd`
2. I need to locate this line and insert another line following this with a pattern `vvss vss`
3. All the other lines below the original line has to be displaced accordingly.

Here is my code so far which inserts into a wrong location:

```
set filename "path265.spi"
set line_no 0
set count 0
set pattern "vvdd vdd"

set fp [open $filename r+]

while {[gets $fp line] != -1} {
    incr count 1
    if {[regexp $pattern $line]} {
        set line_no $count
    }
}

seek $fp 0 
for {set i 0} {$i<$line_no} {incr i} {gets $fp replace}
puts $fp "\nvvnw vnw 0 1.08"

puts $line_no
puts $count
close $fp
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `::fileutil::updateInPlace` to simplify things.

```
package require fileutil

proc change {pattern newtext data} {
    set res {}
    foreach line [split $data \n] {
        lappend res $line
        if {[regexp $pattern $line]} {
            lappend res $newtext
        }
    }
    return [join $res \n]
}

::fileutil::updateInPlace path265.spi {change "^vvdd vdd" "vvss vss"}
```

The `updateInPlace` command takes a file name and a command prefix. It adds the contents of the file to that command prefix and invokes it, then writes the result back to to file.

In this case, the command called iterates through the lines of the file, adding `$newtext` after every line that matches `$pattern`. This is just one way to write the procedure for making the change. If only the first match is relevant, this could be used:

```
proc change {pattern newtext data} {
    set lines [split $data \n]
    set index [lsearch -regexp $lines $pattern]
    if {$index >= 0} {
        set lines [linsert $lines $index+1 $newtext]
    }
    return [join $lines \n]
}
```

etc.

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [linsert](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/linsert.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)